# Plotting data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have entries in two columns in Excel. The first column represents the entity name and the second column represents actual data. For example, the file is like this:

```
clientA    34
clientB    45
clientC    67
clientA    23
clientC    89
```

How can I plot only the second column as 2D-column or 3D-column based on first column?

For example, Excel should represent corresponding values of clientA as "Red", clientB as "Blue", clientC as "Yellow" and second column values should be plotted accordingly (in these colours) and continuously. The names clientA, clientB and clientC should not be plotted, but should be represented as series names on the right hand side of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel 2007 (Excel 2010 may be significantly different but this is an opportunity to provide an image that might illustrate the result you require!):

[image: SO17950037 example]

This has `clientB` and `clientC` corresponding to `clientA` and each series selected separately for formatting with the appropriate (Solid) fill colour. Gap Depth is about 180% and Gap Width about 400%. Horizontal axis labels have been deleted.

Comment: I don't want to rearrange the existing columns in the original file. I mean, here you have put ClientA, ClientB, ClientC in the second row manually. I have literally hundreds of entries and i cannot rearrange manually